# Relative Efficiency of Sample Variance vs Square of Difference

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, efficiency

$\newcommand{\szdp}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\szdb}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\eff}{\operatorname{eff}}$
**Problem Statement:** Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2,\dots, Y_n$ is a random sample from a normal
distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$ Two unbiased estimators
of $\sigma^2$ are
$$\hat\sigma_1^2=S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\szdp{Y_i-\overline{Y}}^{\!2}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\hat\sigma_2^2=\frac12\szdp{Y_1-Y_2}^2.$$
Find the efficiency of $\hat\sigma_1^2$ relative to $\hat\sigma_2^2.$
Note: This is Problem 9.5 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer.

**My Attempt:** Note that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ is $\chi^2$ with $n-1$ d.o.f., by Theorem
7.3, and therefore has variance $2(n-1).$ It follows that
\begin{align*}
V\szdp{\hat\sigma_1^2}
&=V(S^2)\\
&=V\szdp{\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}}\\
&=\frac{\sigma^4}{(n-1)^2}\,V\szdp{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}}\\
&=\frac{\sigma^4}{(n-1)^2}\cdot 2(n-1)\\
&=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}.
\end{align*}
Next, we find (assuming that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent):
\begin{align*}
V\szdp{\hat\sigma_2^2}
&=\frac14\szdb{V\szdp{Y_1^2}+4V\szdp{Y_1Y_2}+V\szdp{Y_2^2}}\\
&=\frac12\szdb{V\szdp{Y_1^2}+2V\szdp{Y_1Y_2}}\\
&=\frac12\szdb{E\szdp{Y_1^4}-\szdp{E\szdp{Y_1^2}}^{\!2}+2E\szdp{Y_1^2Y_2^2}
-2\szdp{E\szdp{Y_1Y_2}}^2}.
\end{align*}
Now some of these values we can obtain by using independence and the fact that
$V(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2.$ To compute $E(Y_1^4),$ we use the moment-generating
function method:
$$E\szdp{Y_1^4}=\left[\frac{d^4}{dt^4}\,\exp\szdp{\mu 
t+\frac{t^2\sigma^2}{2}}\right]_{t=0}=\mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4.$$
Then we continue:
\begin{align*}
V\szdp{\hat\sigma_2^2}
&=\frac12\szdb{E\szdp{Y_1^4}-\szdp{E\szdp{Y_1^2}}^{\!2}
 +2E\szdp{Y_1^2}E\szdp{Y_2^2}-2\szdp{E\szdp{Y_1}E\szdp{Y_2}}^2}\\
&=\frac12\szdb{\mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4
 -(\mu^2+\sigma^2)^2
 +2(\mu^2+\sigma^2)^2
 -2(\mu^2)^2}\\
&=\frac12\szdb{\mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4
 +(\mu^2+\sigma^2)^2
 -2\mu^4}\\
&=\frac12\szdb{4\szdp{2\mu^2\sigma^2+\sigma^4}}\\
&=2\sigma^2\szdp{2\mu^2+\sigma^2}.
\end{align*}
Now then, we compute
\begin{align*}
\eff\szdp{\hat\sigma_1^2,\hat\sigma_2^2}
&=\frac{V\szdp{\hat\sigma_2^2}}{V\szdp{\hat\sigma_1^2}}\\
&=2\sigma^2(2\mu^2+\sigma^2)\cdot\frac{n-1}{2\sigma^4}\\
&=\frac{(2\mu^2+\sigma^2)(n-1)}{\sigma^2}.
\end{align*}

**My Question:** The book's answer is simply $n-1.$ I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, again, but what?

As a comment: I am finding these efficiency calculations to be very tricky; does anyone have suggestions for avoiding mistakes?

Comment: Random sample already means i.i.d observations. So $Y_1-Y_2$ has a Normal distribution and squaring it gives a scaled $\chi^2$ distribution. Check from here if variance of $\hat\sigma_2^2$ is $2\sigma^4$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, thanks, that works! But where's the error in my calculations?